Solidworks API AddMenu not showing
Working on an addin.
Solidwokrs api documentation is very very bad made.
Saw almost every video on youtube on the matter.
Simple thing is not working for me, cannot get why.
Trying to add a menu to the bar.
    public bool ConnectToSW(object ThisSW, int Cookie)
    {
        SwApp = (SldWorks)ThisSW;
        var a = SwApp.AddMenu((int)swDocumentTypes_e.swDocPART, "MyMenu", 0);
        var b = SwApp.AddMenuItem5((int)swDocumentTypes_e.swDocPART, cook, "MyMenu@Tools", 1, "MyMenuCallback", "MyMenuEnableMethod", "My menu item", null);
        return true;
    }

Menu is not showing.
I do get the access to the other functions.
CommandGroup is working thro, but I need only a menu.
        ICommandManager icmd = SwApp.GetCommandManager(cook);
        ICommandGroup cmdGroup;
        cmdGroup = icmd.CreateCommandGroup(1, "test", "tool test", "bla la", 0);
        icmd.AddContextMenu(0, "new");
        int menuToolbarOption = (int)(swCommandItemType_e.swMenuItem | swCommandItemType_e.swToolbarItem);
        cmdGroup.AddCommandItem2("CreateCube", -1, "Create a cube", "Create cube", 0, "CreateCube", "", 0, menuToolbarOption);
        cmdGroup.HasToolbar = true;
        cmdGroup.HasMenu = true;
        cmdGroup.Activate();

Please advice.
Thanks
(Found in the world wide web a post that "AddMenuItem5" probably has a bug, and "AddMenuItem4" does work. is this really a bug, or I'm missing something?)

    public bool ConnectToSW(object ThisSW, int cookie)
            {
                iSwApp = (ISldWorks)ThisSW;
                addinID = cookie;
     
                //Set up callbacks
                iSwApp.SetAddinCallbackInfo2(0, this, addinID);
     
                string[] c=new string[1];
                var a = SwApp.AddMenu((int)swDocumentTypes_e.swDocPART, "MyMenu", 0);
                var b = SwApp.AddMenuItem5((int)swDocumentTypes_e.swDocPART, cook, "Tools@MyMenu", 1, "MyMenuCallback", "MyMenuEnableMethod", "My menu item", c);
                return true;
     
    
            }

 

Use the & symbol to include an accelerator key, e.g., MyItem@, adds MyItem to the File menu with an accelerator key. To display the accelerator key, press the Alt key. The accelerator key is underlined.
For the last argument, you need to pass in an array of strings.
here is the api :AddMenuItem5

No way!!! first - thanks! second its weird, compiler sees no error.  it must be string array, null not accepted. i used null since i found couple demos with it. read api couple times and didnt catch it.
